Hard links on CIFS network mount (ext4) silently falls back to copy operation
I have a CIFS network mount (ext4 on Synology NAS share), and I can't work out why I can't make hard links on that volume – the command is successful and results in a new file, but the new file has its own new inode:
cd /mnt/ds220j
touch hardlinktest.txt
ln hardlinktest.txt hardlinktest2.txt
ls -li .
=>
 1895784 -rwxrwx--- 1 dietpi dietpi  0 Aug  8 09:54  hardlinktest2.txt*
 1895763 -rwxrwx--- 2 dietpi dietpi  0 Aug  8 09:54  hardlinktest.txt*

find . -type f -links 2
=> 
./hardlinktest.txt

find . -type f -samefile ./hardlinktest.txt
=> 
./hardlinktest.txt

ls -li .
=> 
 1895784 -rwxrwx--- 1 dietpi dietpi  0 Aug  8 09:54  hardlinktest2.txt*
 1895763 -rwxrwx--- 1 dietpi dietpi  0 Aug  8 09:54  hardlinktest.txt*

Curiously, the links count initially increments to 2 on the original file, and I can find it using find -links 2, but then afterwards the links count reverts to 1 again and find -links 2 comes back empty.
Mount options via /proc/mounts:
//REDACTED-IP/GLaDOS /mnt/ds220j cifs rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=REDACTED,uid=1000,noforceuid,gid=1000,noforcegid,addr=REDACTED,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,iocharset=utf8,soft,nounix,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,closetimeo=5 0 0

For what it's worth, hard links on the root fs do work just fine.
Any help greatly appreciated 

Do you have anything else running that might be trying to do versioning or compression of files that doesn't understand hardlinks?

@DopeGhoti no, nothing like that. This is on a raspberry pi being used for home automation, and it's running a DNS server and a bunch of docker containers but nothing that deals with versioning or compression, especially on the mount point.

Solved: at some point the mount lost the serverino Samba mount option. I was never explicitly supplying that option, but it was being set by default (confirmed by checking the /proc/mounts options of another CIFS mount with identical options). I added serverino explicitly to the mount options, re-mounted, and now hard links are working again. I can't explain why that option stopped working in the first place, but at least it's fixed now. 
